# I'm searching for a column that is empty how do I make it appear anyway

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a quest to do where I have to get all the details (product_purchase,price_history ,product colums that are name,type,id and price) from just searching for a product id.
right now I have this code

```
SELECT * 
FROM price_history
LEFT JOIN product_purchase on price_history.product_id = product_purchase.product_id
INNER JOIN product ON price_history.product_id = product.id
WHERE product.id = 1
```

The only problem is if the product was never purchased (product.id not on the product_purchase table because it has never been added) it won't show any of the other columns. How do I do so it appears anyway although not existing on product_purchase? I think my answer is the correct one but somehow its not working.

Comment: Seems you should be starting at `product` in your `FROM` and `LEFT JOIN`ing instead.

Comment: Previous question asked by this OP also relevant

Answer (score 1):

You cannot route through your tables in the direction you've chosen, with the join operators you've chosen

```
 price_history LEFT JOIN product_purchase INNER JOIN product
```

Will be evaluated as:

```
price_history LEFT JOIN product_purchase -> result
result INNER JOIN product
```

`price_history left join purchase` will introduce NULLs for any products that have not been purchased.. Then INNER JOIN product onto those "maybe null" rows will remove all the nulls again, because nothing is equal to null, so the `NULL` in the `price_history.product_id` column will not equate to any `product.product_id` value. This means non purchased products will disappear from the results.

When you are planning your table route and don't want to lose rows that "might be null for that column", you should make sure that the table that "might be null" is on the RIGHT side, when you do a LEFT join; the LEFT side of a LEFT join is the "solid" side/the side that always has all the records

To this end, you perhaps need a route like:

```
product 
LEFT JOIN price_history ON product... = price_history...
LEFT JOIN product_purchase ON product... = product_purchase...
```

For any given product, if there is no price history, then the left join will forgive it and keep the product. Same for the product purchase; if there is no purchase the join will be allowed to fail and the product row kept

There are other ways to avoid the issue youre seeing, but generally a good pattern to use is "do all your inner joins first, then do your left joins". If a product absolutely definitely will have at least one price_history, then that could be an INNER JOIN instead of a left

Footnote: don't mention in the WHERE clause a table you have left joined in. Saying something like `WHERE product_purchase.product_id = 1` will undo all your work in crafting a left join, because *nothig is ever equal to a null* so all those rows that were inserted by the LEFT JOIN to ensure the row was kept even though thre was no match, are then suddenly removed again because you compared the NULL with `= 1` in the WHERE clause (and the result is false, so the row disappears from the results)

If you need to predicate on a table that is left joined, consider doing it in the ON, not the WHERE

---

Finally, beware: it seems really likely that both the tables you're joining will have multiple rows per product, which will cause a cartesian explosion. For a product X if there are 2 history rows and 3 purchases you'll get 6 rows, unless you make efforts to tie hisotry and purchases together such that whatever price was operative at the time (from the history) is the one that is accorded to the purchase based on the date the purchase was made

---

Side note, if you inner join products on using the price_history product_id, not the product_purchase product_id, you'll do better, as you'll be inner joining onto a table (price_history) that didn't have introduced nulls from a failed predicate during a left join, but I wanted to talk more about getting you to think about the route to building your dataset and appreciating how the db sticks the data together than just say "change this and it'll work"